# Difference between this Two String Declarations

Tags: java, string, declaration

```
Option 1
++++++++++
String s1;
String s2;
String s3;
```

.

```
Option 2
++++++++++
String s1,s2,s3;
```

I want to know what the actual difference between top two ways of declaring strings.? Any memory or execution speed changes may there.? or both are same .?

Comment: They are the same. You should have put some effort into finding the answer yourself.

Comment: Unless otherwise you are using some other programming languages, where you declare multiple variables on one line, you must make sure each variable is specifically declared. e.g. `VBA`

Comment: Option 2 is less characters to type in.

Comment: Thanks for all for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i check myself like below.

```
public class Declare1 {
    String s1, s2, s3;
}

public class Declare2 { 
    String s1;
    String s2;
    String s3;
}
```

compile each java file and open with text editer each Declare1.class,m Declare2.class..
the.. except unrecognized char.. exactly same.

```
Declare1
java/lang/Object s1 Ljava/lang/String; s2 s3 <init> ()V Code
LineNumberTable LocalVariableTable this 
LDeclare1; 
SourceFile 
Declare1.java

Declare2
java/lang/Object s1 Ljava/lang/String; s2 s3 <init> ()V Code
LineNumberTable LocalVariableTable this 
LDeclare2; 
SourceFile 
Declare2.java
```

after all. compile make a exactly same class file. so each performance will be same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail explanation for this question. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, it's a matter of taste.  The only difference is when you define arrays.  e.g

```
String[] s1, s2[], s3;
```

In this case `s1` and `s3` are `String[]` and `s2` is `String[][]`

Comment: Cool answer...thank you sharing some extra knowledge. +1 for your answer